# Screen Scraping Using Jsoup to Extract Sentences

Tags: java, jsoup, screen-scraping

I want to do some screen scraping and after doing a little research, it appears that JSoup is the best tool for this task. I want to be able to extract all the sentences on a web page; so for example, given this wikipedia page, http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_scraping#Screen_scraping, I want to be able to get all the sentences on that page and print it out to the console. I'm still not familiar with how JSoup works though, so if somebody could help me out that would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First download Jsoup and include it in your project. Then the best place to start is the Jsoup cookbook (http://jsoup.org/cookbook/) as it provides examples for the most common methods you will use with Jsoup. I recommend that you spend some time working through those examples to familiarize yourself with the API. Another good resource is the [javadocs](http://jsoup.org/apidocs/).

Here is a quick example to pull some text from the Wikipedia link you provided:

```
String url = "http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_scraping#Screen_scraping";  

// Download the HTML and store in a Document
Document doc = Jsoup.connect(url).get();

// Select the <p> Elements from the document    
Elements paragraphs = doc.select("p");

// For each selected <p> element, print out its text
for (Element e : paragraphs) {
    System.out.println(e.text());
}
```